# SSH between two servers Linux and AIX

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, aix

I am trying to do passwordless SSH between two server Linux (source) and AIX (destination)

For this i have created public key in Linux server and coped this public key in destination server user profile (in path .ssh/authorized_keys).Also this file is given proper permission.

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config i have uncommented  below

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile        .ssh/authorized_keys
```

But when i am trying to to SSH from Linux to AIX i am getting below error

```
ssh user@AIX-server ls -a
Permission denied, please try again
Permission denied, please try again
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive,hostbased)
```

some debug logs

```
debug1: Trying next Authentication method: publickey
debug1:  Trying public key 
debug2: We did not sent packet, disable method
```

Comment: "Also this file is given proper permission."  What about the directory?  What version of sshd is running on the AIX server?

Comment: @Gerard.Permission given to directory also.How to check what version of sshd running in linux.

Comment: What permission did you give to the directory?  What version of sshd is running on AIX?

Comment: @Gerard 700 for .ssh and 640 for .ssh/authorized_keys.How to check what version of sshd running on AIX ?

Comment: "/usr/sbin/sshd -d" may reveal enough: "debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.9, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019"

Comment: Permissions on authorized_keys may need to be 600.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille SSH version is openSSH_7.4p1.I have also added some debug logs in my main question.

Comment: Generally I tend [to point to this answer of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128910/5462) for SSH troubleshooting.

Comment: On the client side, what uncommented lines do you have in /etc/ssh/ssh_config and .ssh/config ?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the SSHD service `sudo systemctl restart sshd`.

Answer (score 0):

After the configuration change you should restart the sshd service on AIX

```
restartsrc -s sshd
```

Also, you may have forgotten the home directory for the AuthorizedKeysFile

```
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: we have tried restarting sshd in AIX.But still facing same issue.

Comment: @AWS_Beginner this sort of information belongs edited _into_ your question, though.